# Find data from mongodb databse and display it in new html page

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Through ajax request I have get the data form client and save it in mongodb database  (mongoose) through save query .Now I want to know how to find data and display it new page.

I have get the data from client and save it in database. Now I want  that when callback function calls it find data from the database and display it in new page using response.redirect.Please guide me.

```
 $("#saveChanges5").live('click',function(){
            var sendingObj = {
                 regOperation:    $("#area_operation").val()
                ,regFieldAct:    $("#field_activity").val()
                ,regOther:       $("#other_details").val()
            };

            $.ajax({
                url:'/WorkDetails'
                ,type:'post'
                ,data: sendingObj
                ,success:function(){
                    alert('Successfully saved')
                },
                error: function(){
                    alert("Saving Failed")
                }
            })

        });

app.post("/WorkDetails",function(req ,res){
console.log(req.body);
saveWorkDetails(req.body.regOperation ,req.body.regFieldAct ,req.body.regOther  ,function(){
   res.send("");//here i want to add new code

});
```

});

```
function saveWorkDetails(area_operation ,field_activity ,other_details , callback){
console.log("save CALLED");
var receivedObj = new  WorkDetailInfo({
    area_operation:area_operation ,
    field_activity:field_activity ,
    other_details:other_details
});
console.log(receivedObj);
receivedObj.save(function(err){
    console.log("inside Save ");
    if(err){
        //res.send(err);
        console.log(err);
    }
    else{
        callback();
    }
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [narwhal-mongodb](https://github.com/sergi/narwhal-mongodb) APIs
Following is the example usage:

```
var MongoDB = require("mongodb");
var db = new MongoDB.Mongo().getDB("mydb");

var colls = db.getCollectionNames();
colls.forEach(function(el) { print(el); });

var coll = db.getCollection("testCollection");
```